# Saving Auto-Generated ID Into File

Tags: c++

I'm trying to save an auto-generated ID in to my text file, and i'm looking for a suitable method to do this; here are the code snippets

auto-generated id function :

```
int apartment_id() {

    static int id = 100;
    return ++id;

}
```

Getting details of apartment function ( the first if which check the id is just something I've defined in order to go through the loops, I know it doesn't make sense, but it helps the flow :) )

```
   void get_apartment_details(){

    while (true) {



        cout << "Auto-Generated ID:" << apartment_id() << endl;
        cin >> auto_id;
```

and I know that I'm using "cin" while user can't even enter in any data, and in fact, I'm looking for a way to save this random generated integer, without needing user to enter in anything.

**UPDATE:** Here is the function for writing data's in to the text file :

```
    void add_apartment(){

    system("cls");
    staff staffobj;
    staffobj.get_apartment_details();
    progress();
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("apartment.txt", ios::binary | ios::app);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&staffobj), sizeof(staff));
    outFile.close();
    cout << endl << "\n\n Details Of New Apartments Has Been Succesfully Added";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    staff_menu();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by save? To a file? To a structure? What for? You've got a serious issue with the shape of your code. Break/return on failure to avoid those insanely deeply nested ifs. And make functions for the different input types.

Comment: oh yes mat, I wanted to ask that too, you know each time a validation fails it goes again from the beginning. and yes, it's about saving to a text file.

Comment: Well what problem do you have with writing to a text file exactly? There's no code in what you posted that even attempts at saving anything.

Comment: ok mat, as you look very upset, I'm gonna update the question and adding the function for saving into text files

Comment: I'm not upset. I just find it amazing that your whole question is about saving stuff to a text file, yet you initially post it without even mentioning that you are trying to do that, and show pages and pages of code that is completely irrelevant. Please rework your question so that it focuses entirely on the saving part, and produce an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And whatever resource you used that made you think that that `reinterpret_cast` was even remotely a good idea - throw it away/unbookmark it. Read about serialization. And if it's a text file you want, why `binary`?

Comment: You wrote way too much code in this question. **Consider posting only relevant code.**

Comment: it's about saving an integer that has been generated from a function that auto-generates integers. And I've mentioned this as much as I could, none of the codes are irrelevant, I've posted to function that acquire data, function that saves in to text file, and function that auto-generates. I'm using binary and reinterpret_cast as I prefer to do for this project, and it's not about serialization, all I wanted you to do is to help me find a way to store that integer along with other variables in a text file, but you're I guess so generous and friendly, you could not handle that.

Comment: Okay, but what happened now? I think somebody lost the code in your question.

Comment: it's barely 15 lines of code, you get lose in that ? :D

Comment: Don't be rude, because there was irrelevant code, like strings and menus you write in the console.

Comment: I never intended to be rude, I'm just telling you facts friend, it seriously not a lot, it was yes, but I've edited the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is one very easy way to do this, and it's by assigning the function to a variable, as you can see in the code snippet below, I've created an integer called "auto-id", which is in the beginning of my loop, so the first data that will be captured is gonna be this random generated ID ;

```
     void get_apartment_details(){

    while (true) {

        auto_id = nextid();

        cout << "Apartment Name" << endl;

        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, apartment_name);
```

this will save a unique ID along with other data each time you save in the text file